# TYPO3 Backend - Changing record title length in list view

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

When creating new records (e.g. for news) in list view in the backend ... the titles length of each records is cropped to 33 characters (incl. the three ...) if longer.

How can I influence this behavior and show more characters of the created records?

I'm using 7.6.18 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What works is e.g.: In UserTsconfig (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/UserTsconfig/Setup/Index.html)

Backend Users -> Options (of a BE User/Usergroup) -> TSconfig:

```
# Default User value
setup.default.titleLen = 80
setup.override.titleLen= 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set titel length limit for all records in backend. set this limit in `User Settings`. See attched image.

[image: set Title character limits]